# Fail to call the CUDA solver in tensorflow (cuSolverDN call failed with status =7)

Tags: python, tensorflow

Hello I tried to build a tensorflow neural network with some CuDNNLSTM layers and it failed to call a cuda solver. Since the error does not occur when I remove the CuDNNLSTM layer, I think it has something to do with the LSTM layer.

```
class ActorNet:

    def __init__(self, N_STATES, N_ACTIONS, MAX_STEP, BATCH_SIZE, lr_a):

        self.N_STATES = N_STATES
        self.N_ACTIONS = N_ACTIONS
        self.MAX_STEP = MAX_STEP
        self.BATCH_SIZE = BATCH_SIZE
        self.lr_a = lr_a
        self.g = tf.Graph()
        self.cwd = os.getcwd()
        self.path = os.path.join(self.cwd, 'simple') + "\\model.ckpt"

        with self.g.as_default():

            self.sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
            self.a_input_states = tf.placeholder("float", [self.MAX_STEP, None, self.N_ACTIONS + self.N_STATES + 1],
                                                 name='input_placeholder')
            self.a_input_states_tp = tf.transpose(self.a_input_states, [1,0,2])
            self.a_grad_from_critic = tf.placeholder("float", [1, None, self.N_ACTIONS], name='input_placeholder')

            with tf.variable_scope('actor'):

                self.model = models.Sequential()
                self.model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
                self.model.add(layers.CuDNNLSTM(500, return_sequences=True))
                self.model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
                self.model.add(layers.CuDNNLSTM(500, return_sequences=True))
                self.model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
                self.model.add(layers.CuDNNLSTM(500, return_sequences=True))
                self.model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
                self.model.add(layers.CuDNNLSTM(500, return_sequences=True))
                self.model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
                self.model.add(layers.CuDNNLSTM(500, return_sequences=True))
                self.model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
                self.model.add(layers.Dense(self.N_ACTIONS, activation='tanh'))

                self.lstm_output = self.model(self.a_input_states_tp)
                self.lstm_output_tp = tf.transpose(self.lstm_output, [1, 0, 2])

            self.params = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope='actor')

            self.gradient = tf.gradients(self.lstm_output_tp[-1:,:,:], self.params, -self.a_grad_from_critic / self.BATCH_SIZE)
            self.gradient_a = tf.gradients(self.lstm_output_tp[-1:,:,:], self.a_input_states)

            self.opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.lr_a)
            self.optimizer = self.opt.apply_gradients(zip(self.gradient, self.params))

            print("Initialized Actor Network...")

            self.t_a_input_states = tf.placeholder("float", [self.MAX_STEP, None, self.N_ACTIONS + self.N_STATES + 1],
                                                   name='input_placeholder')
            self.t_a_input_states_tp = tf.transpose(self.t_a_input_states, [1,0,2])
            self.t_a_grad_from_critic = tf.placeholder("float", [self.MAX_STEP, None, self.N_ACTIONS],
                                                       name='input_placeholder')

            with tf.variable_scope('target_actor'):

                self.t_model = models.Sequential()
                self.t_model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
                self.t_model.add(layers.CuDNNLSTM(500, return_sequences=True))
                self.t_model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
                self.t_model.add(layers.CuDNNLSTM(500, return_sequences=True))
                self.t_model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
                self.t_model.add(layers.CuDNNLSTM(500, return_sequences=True))
                self.t_model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
                self.t_model.add(layers.CuDNNLSTM(500, return_sequences=True))
                self.t_model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
                self.t_model.add(layers.CuDNNLSTM(500, return_sequences=True))
                self.t_model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
                self.t_model.add(layers.Dense(self.N_ACTIONS, activation='tanh'))

                self.t_lstm_output = self.t_model(self.t_a_input_states_tp)
                self.t_lstm_output_tp = tf.transpose(self.t_lstm_output, [1, 0, 2])

            self.t_params = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope='target_actor')

            print("Initialized Target Actor Network...")

            self.sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

            self.sess.run([t_param.assign(self.params[ii]) for ii, t_param in enumerate(self.t_params)])

            self.update_target_actor_op = [t_param.assign(TAU * self.params[ii] + (1-TAU) * t_param) for ii, t_param in enumerate(self.t_params)]

            self.saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=200)
```

When I call it, for example

```
ActorNet(10, 3, 30, 20, 0.001)
```

Then it throws the error.

```
InternalError (see above for traceback): tensorflow/core/kernels/cuda_solvers.cc:468: cuSolverDN call failed with status =7
     [[Node: actor/sequential/cu_dnnlstm/recurrent_kernel/Initializer/Qr = Qr[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@actor/sequential/cu_dnnlstm/recurrent_kernel"], full_matrices=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](actor/sequential/cu_dnnlstm/recurrent_kernel/Initializer/random_normal)]]
```

The error occurs at

```
self.sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

The error does not occur when I removed the LSTM layers.
I am using Tensorflow 1.9.0, Cuda 10.1, and RTX 2080.
What can I do to solve this problem? I tried setting a random seed for the tf session but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved exactly this issue by updating tensorflow-gpu 1.9.0 to 1.11.0, don't really know was it caused by 1.9.0?
And both Tensorflow 1.9.0 and 1.11.0 are supposed to use Cuda 9.0 btw.